# Tools for checking correctness of algebraic operations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have many cases for which this question is relevant but one case would be the following. Are there any computer-aided tools for checking the correctness of expanding algebraic expressions such as 
$$
\begin{align}
    (\mathbf{Xw}-\mathbf{t})^T(\mathbf{Xw}-\mathbf{t}) &= ((\mathbf{Xw})^T-\mathbf{t}^T)(\mathbf{Xw}-\mathbf{t})\\
    &= (\mathbf{Xw})^T\mathbf{Xw} - (\mathbf{Xw})^T\mathbf{t} - \mathbf{t}^T\mathbf{Xw} + \mathbf{t}^T\mathbf{t}\\
    &= \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{Xw}-\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{t} - \mathbf{t}^T\mathbf{Xw} + \mathbf{t}^T\mathbf{t}
    %\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{X}^T
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What kinds of things do the variables represent?  From the indications of "transpose", I suspect matrices are involved, but a mixture of upper and lower case will often denote matrices vs. scalars.  In any case it's a good idea to share what is known about the dimensions of the matrices, and which (if any) are scalar quantities.

Comment: Ah, in this case, the lower cases bold letters represent vectors and bold upper cases represent matrices. However, that was just to provide an example of what a possible CAD tools should be able to check the correctness of :)